# send data from script to script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send an object from a script to a modal and from that modal to a script, but i dont know how I can do it:
my first script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add").click(function () {
            $.getJSON("/api/ticket", function (result) {
                var msg = "";
                var buyInput = "";
                $.each(result, function (i, field) {
                    buyInput ="{date:"+ field.date +
                        ",destination:" + field.destination +
                        ",flightNumber:" + field.flightNumber +
                        ",source:" + field.source +
                    "}";



                    msg += "<tr><td>" + field.flightNumber + "</td><td>" + field.source + "</td><td>"
                        + field.destination + "</td>";
                    msg += "<td >" + field.date + "</td>";
                    msg += "<td>" +
                        "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"  data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" data-id=buyInput>Buy</button></td></tr>";
               });
                $("#tbl").append(msg);
            });
        });
    });
```

my modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Enter your name.</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" id="name">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" id="buyTicket">Buy.</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my final script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#buyTicket").click(function () {

            var url = "/api/ticket/";
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var flight = $(this).data('id');
            $("#buyInput").val( flight );
            var arr = {
                flight: flight,
                person: {
                    fullName: name
                }
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(arr),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (data, status) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

in the first script I get some data from the database (flight data) when the user click on buy button the modal appears and get the user's name and when the user click on buy button on the modal, the name and flight data should go to the last script to complete the jason for post method.
I dont know how to send the flight data.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
   $("#buyTicket").click(function ()
```

With below line

```
   $(document).on("click","#buyTicket",function ()
```